# What privacy methods exist for P2P transfers?

Tags: privacy, anonymity, p2p

I love my VPN, it gives me to a certain extent privacy from isp & to what I connect.

I also use P2P to get & provide data, but I would like to create a level of privacy. What methods exist for P2P anonymity and privacy?

Answer (score 1):

Well the only way to anonymize  your P2P is to use an overlay network. So this means using proxies/VPN's/Tor like networks.

Another option would be to use a server that is not registered in your name and that doesn't log anything.

There are also options where it is hard to get onto the P2P network. You can only get  onto their network when you are invited and trusted. These networks are called Private Trackers. It's not 100% anonymous, but more based on web of trust.